# How do I Override ToString in a Composite Type in F#?

Tags: f#, overriding, composite-types

I'm learning about creating composite* types in F# and I ran into a problem.  I have this type and a ToString override.

```
type MyType =
    | Bool of bool
    | Int of int
    | Str of string
    with override this.ToString() =
            match this with
            | Bool -> if this then "I'm True" else "I'm False"
            | Int -> base.ToString()
            | Str -> this

let c = Bool(false)
printfn "%A" c
```

I get an error inside the ToString override that says "This constructor is applied to 0 argument(s) but expects 1".  I was pretty sure this code wouldn't compile, but it shows what I'm trying to do.  When I comment out the override and run the code, `c` is printed out as "val c : MyType = Bool false".  When I step into that code, I see that c has a property `Item` set to the boolean `false`.  I can't seem to access this property in the code however.  Not even if I annotate `c`.

How should I be overriding ToString in this situation?

* *I'm pretty sure these are called composite types.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you are using a [Discriminated Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx) (DU) (that's the appropriate name for that type), you need to unpack the value in the match statement like this:

```
type MyType =
    | Bool of bool
    | Int of int
    | Str of string
    with override this.ToString() =
            match this with
            | Bool(b) -> if b then "I'm True" else "I'm False"
            | Int(i) -> i.ToString()
            | Str(s) -> s

let c = Bool(false)
printfn "%A" c
```

The `Item` property that you're seeing is an implementation detail and is not intended to be accessed from F# code.  Merely using `this` doesn't work because the DU is a wrapper around the value, so `this` refers to the wrapper, not to the contained value.